# query non-deterministically hanging on self._clslevel[target] = collections.deque()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a program running the following query via the Sql Alchemy ORM. At this particular point in the code, it is running serially.

```
//ms sql database setup
engine = create_engine(conn_string, pool_size=pool_size, pool_recycle=3600, echo=False)
engine.execute('set transaction isolation level read uncommitted')
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=autocommit))

//hangs in here
max_id = session.query(func.max(entity.entity_id)).all()[0][0]
```

Occasionally, the program hangs as if it is deadlocked. Execution does not proceed for hours. I have ruled out any issues in database connection or blocked queries as a periodic stack trace of my main calling thread shows the execution hanging at the following spot (see StackTrace below).

It seems like a dictionary is being updated. If SqlAlchemy were to be trying to do anything fancy with threads underneath the hood, `weakref.py` uses a `WeakValueDictionary` from https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakValueDictionary, in which `self.data` is a native python dictionary which should be safe under concurrent access.

**What could be causing this intermittent hanging?** I am on SQL Alchemy `1.0.12` and Python `3.5.2`.

```
File "/home/me/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2588, in all
  return list(self)
File "/home/me/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2732, in __iter__
  context = self._compile_context()
File "/home/me/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3180, in _compile_context
  if self.dispatch.before_compile:
File "/home/me/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/base.py", line 288, in __get__
  obj.__dict__['dispatch'] = disp = self.dispatch_cls._for_instance(obj)
File "/home/me/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/base.py", line 110, in _for_instance
  return self._for_class(instance_cls)
File "/home/me/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/base.py", line 106, in _for_class
  return self.__class__(self, instance_cls)
File "/home/me/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/base.py", line 84, in __init__
  for ls in parent._event_descriptors
File "/home/me/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/base.py", line 84, in <genexpr>
  for ls in parent._event_descriptors
File "/home/me/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 188, in __init__
  parent.update_subclass(target_cls)
File "/home/me/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 125, in update_subclass
  self._clslevel[target] = collections.deque()
File "/home/me/py35/lib/python3.5/weakref.py", line 378, in __setitem__
  self.data[ref(key, self._remove)] = value
```